# VS Code: Go to next/previous member

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension or built-in action that allows me to go to the next/previous member of the currently open C# class?

Answer (score 2):

For versions [1.59 and up](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_navigate-between-folding-regions), you can get very close to this functionality with built-in commands (no extension needed), by mapping keyboard shortcuts to the following commands:

- Go to Previous Folding Range (`editor.gotoNextFold`)
- Go to Next Folding Range (`editor.gotoPreviousFold`)

For example, on a Mac, I mapped the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Dn</kbd>, respectively (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up/Dn</kbd> is stolen by MacOS).

**Also note**: it may seem like this only works for one level of folding, but not to worry: you just have to press up/down to "get into" the area of code encompassed by the next folding level, and then you can keep using the shortcuts above. For example:

- If I'm at the very top of a file, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Dn</kbd> will get me to the class name (and then stops).
- To go to the next member in the class, press <kbd>Dn</kbd> arrow to go into the next folding level. Then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Dn</kbd> again to jump to other members.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution-extension** – https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mishkinf.goto-next-previous-member#overview

From  [Go to next method shortcut in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388358/go-to-next-method-shortcut-in-vscode)

> To achieve this I have developed an extension that provides two key
>   commands to navigate up and down through the members in your file.
>
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mishkinf.goto-next-previous-member#overview
>
> ```
> Visual Studio Code Extension to navigate through the functions, variables, and classes using quick and easy keycommands similar to
> ```
>
> functionality provided by IntelliJ IDE's (next/previous function) or
>   Resharper (next/previous member)
>
> Let me know if there any features you would like added.