# Go to next method shortcut in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VSCode have shortcut to move to next method definition in the same file? I can't find anything like this in settings.

IntelliJ has this feature, for example, you can find this as **Next Method** in settings

Comment: Have you found any way to do this? The closest I have gotten is the `Got to Bracket` (Ctrl+Shift+`) shortcut. It takes you to the nearest bracket, then pressing it again takes you to the matching bracket.

Not at all what you were asking for above, as it does not move to the next method after getting to the closing bracket.

A bit surprising they left out such an important shortcut. Please let the rest of us know if you found a solution :)

Comment: @Magnus, unfortunately no :)

Comment: Still looking for this...

Comment: To partly solve this problem I use the "smoothscroll" plugin. With this you can at least move the cursor x lines at the time.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To achieve this I have developed an extension that provides two key commands to navigate up and down through the members in your file.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mishkinf.goto-next-previous-member#overview

> Visual Studio Code Extension to navigate through the functions, variables, and classes using quick and easy keycommands similar to functionality provided by IntelliJ IDE's (next/previous function) or Resharper (next/previous member)

Let me know if there any features you would like added.

Comment: Hi Mishkin, I'm using your extension, thanks a lot for it, I just wonder how to allow the navigation between methods only, or at least static members instead those ones inside any method as variable declarations, cheers.

Comment: @CarlosTeevin yeah thank you Carlos for the question! It shouldn’t be a very complicated task. I can add it to the wish list of features on the github repo if you’d like. I won’t be able to get to it for a little while though. Or if you want to submit a PR I would be happy to look at it. Check out the repository link for the extension.

Comment: Hi Mishkin, I have enabled your extension, but pressing ctrl-up or down does not have any effect. I am new to using custom VSC extensions. Could you provide more guidance on how to use your extension?

Comment: @yellowjacket05 works out of the box for me. You could try checking your keyboard shortcuts for conflicts. What language are you using?

Comment: Hi Mishkin! I've installed your extension, and am trying to use it with python. Instead of jumping to the next function, it just jumps to the next variable defined in the function. I do have Microsoft's python extension enabled. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 83):

Old question, but I found interacting with the breadcrumb useful. `ctrl-shift-.` takes focus to the breadcrumb and up and down arrows move through the outline, with the bonus that the editor follows.

Comment: for people who use mac, it is `cmd+shift+.`

Comment: But breadcrumbs are sorted alphabetically, not following file-order;  practically you move randomly throughout the file :-(

Comment: For me, it works just fine; and its NOT sorted but it is in file order (C++).

Comment: same for me it's in file order (see Go, Rust, Python)

Answer (score 20):

Another option is to use `Go to Symbol in Editor` default hotkey is `Ctrl+Shift+o`.
Then type `:` for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have few notes about others solutions and my own:

- [Malks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64811642/14937497) solution is great for MacOS this worked for me `cmd+shift+.`
- [Mishkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49995264/14937497) using a specific extension probably is the ideal solution, however it **didn't** work for me in MacOS tried to remap to my own shortcuts and config it still nothing worked.
- [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060921/14937497) solution takes you to a specific line (which can be directly achieved by `CMD+L` in MacOS).

---

Eventually the best solution **for me** at least is to start picking up the basics of VIM motions and install the Vim extension.

in my setting.json:

`"editor.linernumber": "relative"`

now in insert mode writing k+{line-number} will take me to the line immediately I want to go to

Without vim motion is possible you will use `CMD+L`.

However, we would like to move from one function to the other in-which we will:

> this highly dependable on your language thought (you can config and create your own binding).

In python you can use: `]m` and `[m` . ([readthis](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/748))

and so on.

---

Another option much easier than picking-up VIM-motions, is to use this extension [Jump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.jump) (Publisher: Wenfang  Du)

It will send the cursoer to start/end of a specific word (you can use it mutliple times to reach a specific function).

`OPT/ALT+Q OPT/ALT+W`: is the default to jump to end of a word (change this shortcut to somethign faster).